# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Can I have an action name with a slash in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

What I want to do is have a page at `/Products/Details/{id}`, which routes to the action details on `ProductsController` and also an edit page at `/Products/Details/Edit/{id}`.

I tried to do this using `[ActionName("Details/Edit")]` on the action but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just call it EditDetails?

Comment: Because that doesn't match the URL I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a slash in your action name.

Why not have the following actions?

- /Products/Details/{id}   -For display
- /Products/Edit/{id}   -For edit

My preference would be to do the following:

- /Products/{id}/View   -For display
- /Products/{id}/Edit/  -For edit

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: because each product has a number of views. Details, history, documents etc, Each of these pages is to be presented in a view and edit form.

Comment: However I do like the routing pattern you describe. /Products/{id}/Details and /Products/{id}/Details/Edit would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I would go even further and just remove the /Details/ for viewing a product i.e. /products/{id} and editing could be /products/edit/{id}

Answer (score 1):

Add route like this ***BEFORE*** the default one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithDetails",
    "{controller}/Details/{action}/{id}"},
    null);
```

Comment: +1 to do what JayArr requested, though I think that semantically Lewis' suggestion is a better idea.

Comment: James, yes. I agree. But I just was answering the question :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this. Setup a new route like this before the default route;

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "PRoute", 
     "{controller}/{action}/{action2}/{id}", 
     null   
 );
```

then in your Products controller have your action like this, notice that the parameter names match the names in the route.

```
public ActionResult Details(string action2, string id)
{
    switch (action2)
    {
        case "edit":
            // Do Something.
            return View("edit");
        case "view":
            // Do Something.
            return View("view");
       default :
            // Do Something.
            return View("bad-action-error");
    }
}
```

Now the Details action will be passed action2 and the id from the url.
So a URL like /products/details/view/7 the details action will get "view" and "7" , then you can use a switch or if statement on action2 to continue your processing. This can now easily be expanded to include other sub-actions.